# Veracrypt FDE on Ubuntu?

Tags: encryption, veracrypt

Can you perform a full disk encryption on a system drive with Veracrypt in Ubuntu? I remember reading somewhere that Veracrypt can't do FDE on a system drive under Linux, but can't seem to find that anywhere, so perhaps it can now do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point, [according to VeraCrypt documentation](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Supported%20Systems%20for%20System%20Encryption.html), only Windows operating systems are supported, and you cannot use Veracrypt to fully encrypt a Linux disk.